# jquery - add different class for each anchor element when hover

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass

so I'm new into jquery and I was messing around but I ran into a problem.

I got this menubar with 5 elements and I want to add a class to each element when I hover over them.

example: When I hover over "dishes" I want to add class active, but the other 4 elements should get the class inactive. And I want to remove these classes whenever I hover out.How do I this?

thanks in advance!

jquery

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("nav").hover(
       function () {
          $(this).addClass("active");
       },
       function () {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
      }
     );
    });
```

html

```
    <header>
<h1>Sushi Lovers</h1>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
    <li> <a href="#">Dishes</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Lunch</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Diner</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Reservations</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact us</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the `a` tag to add the class

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav li a").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).addClass("active").parents('ul').find('li a').not($(this)).addClass('inactive');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).parents('ul').find('li a').removeClass('active inactive');
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rFEER/45/)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! But now it only gives the one Im hovering class "active", but at the same I want to other elements to have the class "inactive". Perhaps you know how to do this?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted! This seem to be a quite stupid question, but how come the menu is changing color/font etc.? When I hover over it, it turns red.

Comment: @user3189660 you need to write css for those class to apply style

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the hover for anchor tags individually

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("nav").find("a").hover(
       function () {
          $("nav").find("a").not(this).addClass("inactive")
          $(this).addClass("active");
       },
       function () {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          $(".inactive").removeClass("active");
      }
     );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(".nav li").hover(
   function () {
      $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
      $(this).addClass("active");
   },
   function () {
      $('.active').removeClass("active");
      $('.inactive').removeClass("inactive");
  });
```

you can update your css like this:

```
li.active a{
  /* your css props */
}
li.inactive a{
  /* your css props */
}
```